# How to add two numbers in sugar crm

Tags: sugarcrm

I made module addition and in this made three fields `amount1_c`, `amount2_c` and `total_amount_c` to add the two numbers and display the result in the third field. I done coding in the logic looks here is my code

```
<?
$hook_version = 1;     
$hook_array = Array();      
$hook_array['before_save'] = Array();     
$hook_array['before_save'][] = Array(1,'calculate_field', 'custom/modules/cases/LogicHookMath.php','LogicHookMath', 'calculate_field');    
?>
```

and made one more file logic hook math. here is my code for

```
<?php
class LogicHookMath {
    function calculate_field(&$bean, $event, $arguments) {
        $field1 = $bean->amount1_c;
        $field2 = $bean->amount2_c;
        $field3 = $field1 + $field2;
        $bean->amount_total_c = $field3;
    }
}
?>
```

but still i did not get any result. Please help me out for this.

Comment: Have you tried adding a die statement at the very top of the function to confirm that the logic hook is being called?  Something simple like `die("I got called")`.  If that works, try `die($bean->amount1_c)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks correct.

Some common "mistakes" when custom logic hooks are not working:

- Make sure, the custom logic hook has the correct name (`LogicHookMath.php`)
- Make sure, that the `$bean` variable is prefixed with `&`, so the variable is passed as a reference
- Make sure the `logic_hooks.php` and the `LogicHookMath.php` files are readable by the web server user
- The entire custom directory should also be writeable for the web server user

If the above does not help, try logging the progress to the sugarcrm.log using `$GLOBALS['log']->info( "Value 3: ". $field3);` in the custom logic hook.